# Vuetify + Vuex + vuex-map-fields: v-data-table with a v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I have a `v-data-table`, and one of the columns is a `v-select`
The data is stored in vuex, and I use `vuex-map-fields` to retrieve/update

The UI is (simplified)

```
<v-data-table
  :items="data"
>
  <template v-slot:item.type="{ item }">
    <v-select
      v-model="?"
      :items="types"
      item-text="description"
    />
  </template> 
</v-data-table>
```

And the data is (simplified)

```
data: [
    {
        .
        .
        type: <some_uuid_1>
    },
    {
        .
        .
        type: <some_uuid_2>
    }   
],

types: [
    {
        id: <some_uuid_1>,
        description: "first"
    },
    {
        id: <some_uuid_2>,
        description: "second"
    }   
]
```

**What I am trying to do**

I'm tring to "map" the `v-model` of the `v-select` in such a way that the root data object (`data`) is updated correctly.emphasized text

*Rephrased*

If I pick from the `v-select` in any row in the `v-data-table` the corresponding item in `data` is updated

**Notes**: `vuex-map-fields` is a library that saves me writing getters/mutations

Comment: Have you tried setting the `v-model="item.type"` and also adding `item-value="id"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's a mixup with the vue chrome devtools, the state wasn't updating in the vue extension but it actually is being updated. (should I just delete the question?)